# No freeze attribute when using Dataset module in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I'm currently trying to implement a form of twitter data analysis. I've already got a code up and running to pull data using the Streaming API, and all I have to do is save the data in a csv file.

```
result = db[settings.TABLE_NAME].all()
dataset.freeze(result, format='csv', filename=settings.CSV_NAME)
```

From what I saw in the documentation, this should be the right way of declaring this. I've defined `Table.Name` and `CSV_Name` in another file settings.py.

When running `python dump.py`, it gives me this error.

```
AttributeError: module 'dataset' has no attribute 'freeze'
```

I'm trying to replicate the code from [Streaming Data](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/streaming-data-python/), if that helps pinpoint the issue. I've cloned the repo to my Desktop, and only added my Twitter authentication data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version dataset 1.0, module dataset is split into two packages, with the data export features now extracted into a stand-alone package, datafreeze.

So install `datafreeze`

`pip install datafreeze`

Then

`from datafreeze import freeze`

or

`from datafreeze.app import freeze`

Both should work.

Comment: I installed datafreeze using anaconda prompt. Even after putting `from datafreeze import freeze`, I got the same error. I just get an additional warning, `datafreeze.freeze imported but unused`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Please, give me the code how you used? May be you haven't edited your code line.Change this line `dataset.freeze(result, format='csv', filename=settings.CSV_NAME)` into `freeze(result, format='csv', filename=settings.CSV_NAME)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to share code other than copying the entire thing. Sorry, I just joined today. Thanks for the switching though! Just `freeze(result, format='csv', filename=settings.CSV_NAME)` worked fabulously!

Comment: Good to know :)