# Streaming twitter data and saving to csv in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, export-to-csv, sentiment-analysis

I’m trying to follow this [tutorial](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/streaming-data-python/) on streaming tweets from twitter into a database, before then converting the database to a CSV file. I can implement the streaming API feature to capture data fine, however when trying to save the data in a csv file I am having problems.

At first I encountered a similar problem to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48090148/no-freeze-attribute-when-using-dataset-module-in-python) where I receive the following error.

```
    AttributeError: module 'dataset' has no attribute 'freeze'
```

The solution removes the error when running the script but I am left with no CSV file and empty DB file instead.

I have looked over all the documentation but I'm really unsure on what I am doing wrong and how I can proceed.

[My GitHub with all source code can be found here](https://github.com/andypejo/TweetScrape)

Comment: could you verify that the code is receiving tweets correctly in the first place?

Comment: To be honest I am pretty new to this so I'm a bit unsure and confused. I have tried simpler versions of this which pulls the tweets and writes to a .JSON file which works fine, it just seems to be when I try to implement the next step I'm having problems

Example of simple script - https://pastebin.com/z0FKLCJm

Comment: Reproduced the error. Tweets are saved to the db just fine. Maybe it's necessary to use a specific version of python and/or the used packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all I think that storing your tweets from stream in CSV file is a bad idea, and use MongoDB or another database where you will store your data.

Good example how you can ***organize streaming and storing tweets in database***  you can find on [this github repository](https://github.com/SamDelgado/twitter-to-mongo)

Before inserting tweet to database, ***it's better to calculate sentiment score for tweet in advance***. Sentiment analysis can be done by using [VADER](https://github.com/cjhutto/vaderSentiment) sentiment analysis tool.

Good luck)